# What is the difference between IXON and IXOFF tty attributes?

Tags: tty, pty

To be specific, let's speak in pseudo-terminal terms. Suppose we have file descriptors `master` and `slave` for a pseudo-terminal pair (suppose it is a controlling tty). Disabling `IXON` on `master` (or `slave`, which works the same) means that when we do `write(master, &control_s_code, 1)`, `read(slave, &byte, 1)` will get this code. The same concerns `control_q_code`. The question is: what does disabling `IXOFF` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IXOFF` is not implemented on pseudo-ttys, and setting `IXOFF` on a pseudo-tty has no effect whatsoever.

`IXOFF` should cause the tty driver to send a `VSTOP` character to the other side when its input queue is full (which should prevent it from sending in more data), and a `VSTART` character when it has processed it and there's place for more data.

This is different from `IXON`, which will cause the tty driver to respect the `VSTART`/`VSTOP` characters sent from the other side, and upon receiving a `VSTOP` (`^S`) character, stop any transmission until a `VSTART` (`^Q`) character is received.

In the case of a pseudo-tty, the "other side" is the master pty, eg. your terminal emulator; when you press `^S`, it's the `IXON`, not the `IXOFF` setting which will cause the slave tty to stop echoing back the entered characters and displaying the data written to it (which will be queued until the output queue is full, when any `write(2)` to the slave tty will either block or return `EAGAIN`).

Implementing flow control on pseudo-ttys is not needed, because the kernel always knows (by checking a struct field or similar) whether the input queue of the slave has filled up, and can just block the process writing to the master pty.

The software flow control is only useful when using a real serial connection *without* out-of-band signals like RTS/CTS: unlike any Unix, TCP or other "pipe" abstraction, a wire is not buffering and will not fill up and block until the receiver has read all the state changes off it.

Comment: ok, thanks! I never really got the logic in the ixon/ixoff naming, I always wondered why they're not called "sendxoff" and "recvxoff" or something like that instead. (Anyway, now I can go back to being confused about other things!)

Comment: What does `IXOFF` do for an ordinary (i.e., not pseudo) tty?

Comment: Also, your note about absence of need for flow control on pseudo terminals is not known to `gnome-terminal` (and `xterm`) developers: pressing `^S` in bash can be used to verify this.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Whether the pty reacts to `^S`/`^Q` is controlled by the `IXON`, not the `IXOFF` settings; I've expanded on that in the answer. The terminal emulator doesn't have to care about that at all -- it simply writes the `^S` and `^Q` characters into the master fd -- it's up to the tty driver to handle or not handle them.

Comment: So, `IXOFF` is the same as `IXON`, but for the opposite side of the tty. Right?

Comment: You say: "Whether the pty reacts to ^S/^Q is controlled by the IXON, not the IXOFF settings". Why pty is supposed to react to ^S/^Q sent from master side but cannot react to ^S/^Q sent from slave side? I think it should be both or none.

Comment: No. With a real serial line, setting either `IXON` or `IXOFF` does not affect in any way what the remote side will do. What may be confusing is that any line discipline ioctls (eg. `TIOCSETS*` which implement `tcsetattr`) on the master pty are always acting on the __slave__ pty. The master pty is not a real pty, and does not do any line discipline like flow control or anything, it simply reads and writes raw data to the slave. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529927/308316) for some details about how it works in Linux.

Comment: You say: "setting either IXON or IXOFF does not affect in any way what the remote side will do". But this contradicts to what you said in the answer: "IXOFF should cause the tty driver to send a VSTOP character to the other side".

Comment: Is there any example scenario when disabling IXON on master side of pty may be harmful?

Comment: How could changing any property of the __local__ tty driver affect the system/device at the other end of the wire, whether making it use or not use flow control?

Comment: You cannot change any line discipline property on the master pty -- any `tcsetattr` on the master will only affect the slave. The master fd is simply set to raw mode / pass-through and is not user-serviceable.

Comment: If device on the "other side" uses flow control, setting IXOFF on local tty driver will stop the device from sending any more data

Comment: No, it will only cause the local device to send the VSTART/VSTOP characters -- the other side may ignore them or treat them as ordinary characters ;-)

Comment: Yes, but **if** that device does not ignore them, setting **local** tty attributes **will** change state of the device. So, saying that changing local tty attributes will change state of device on the other side of the wire, is not wrong.

Comment: Is there any example scenario, when disabling IXON using master fd of pty, may be harmful? I mean, why it was decided to leave possibility of software flow control for pty anyway (for IXON)?

Comment: For example, I patched `vte2.91` to disable `IXON` using master fd right after pty is created (to get rid of annoying effects of pressing ^S in bash and other programs). Is this bad in any way?

Comment: It depends on the app. If it's something like `expect`, the answer is certainly NO. If it's a terminal emulator, a user may expect to stop scrolling with `^S`, and will hate you if she has to look in the manual how to enable it back ;-)

Comment: There was no need to patch vte; simply `stty -ixon` in `~/.bashrc` would've worked, too.

Comment: In such scenario each program which does not use ^S (e.g., `less`, `bash`) must be patched/configured to disable IXON, which is worse than patching just one terminal emulator. And finally I see the use case for ^S/^Q in bash - scrolling! Never occurred to me before. But I deal with this problem in another way - I use unlimited scroll buffer.

Comment: No, simply `stty -ixon` [works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478546/308316) -- `less`, `vi` or the readline library (as used by `bash`) will not reenable it back.